# How can one reset Arduino Nano from NodeMCU?

Tags: arduino-nano, nodemcu

If one connects the `RESET` pin on an Arduino Nano to a digital pin on a NodeMCU, will the NodeMCU be able to reset the Nano by setting said pin to `LOW`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reset a 5 V Arduino with esp8266. I did it many times. The esp8266 doesn't have a problem with pull-up level current at 5 V.

On my picture io 0 of the esp-12F is wired to reset pin of Nano. The esp-12F runs [WiFiLink firmware](https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-firmware-wifilink/wiki/Test-Setup) which can OTA upload sketch to ATmega328p and of course before flashing it must reset the ATmega.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes - grounding the reset pin over-rides the pullup resistor on the Atmega 328's reset pin. You may not be able to prevent the NodeMCU from resetting the Nano when it (NodeMCU) is reset, if that matters.

Comment: esp8266 doesn't set pins LOW at startup

Comment: Good to know - thanks.

Comment: that matters.  tks for the headsup, UPVOTED.

Answer (score 1):

yes it can.

and to make this answer a little longer...

1. you don't need a level shifter as the pins are 5v tolerant. pullups aren't a problem
2. you may use an optocoupler for isolation :)

Comment: interesting, UPVOTED